# Xacro arguments not appearing in MoveIt! Setup Assistant

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and on ROS Kinetic. I have worked with MoveIt! several times and I had to change my MoveIt! package more than one time because I added more links and joints to my URDF model. At the time, I launched the moveit setup assistant and clicked on "Edit Existing MoveIt Configuration Package" and selected the path to the MoveIt! config package that I had previously created. After that I would write arguments in a text box named XACRO arguments (or someting like this) in order to load some parts of my model (because my original URDF is the Husky robot and I am also loading other additional parts like the kinetic, etc.). The problem is that this XACRO arguments text box used to appear below the text box were I type the path for my MoveIt! config package, but now it's not appearing anymore and I don't know why. This makes it impossible for me to even load and see correctly my MoveIt! config package in the Setup Assistant and I also can't alter it like I want. Do you know why this is happening?

Best regards,
José Brito

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289106/xacro-arguments-not-appearing-in-moveit!-setup-assistant/) by [znbrito](https://answers.ros.org/users/34507/znbrito/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2018-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The xacro argument field was added only recently [in March](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/commit/dc868e336cbee987b783f2896320779312dfe1f2) and has not been released yet.
If you want to use it at the moment, make sure you build moveit from source in the `kinetic-devel` branch.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2018-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [znbrito](https://answers.ros.org/users/34507/znbrito/) on 2018-04-24**:
Hello @v4hn, thanks for your answer. Yes you are right, I used Synaptic to delete all my MoveIt! pacakges and then I downloaded and compiled everything from source in the kinetic branch and now the text box appeared again! Thanks a lot! :)